# Is there a function to overlay a density map over a street map in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, r-mapview

I am trying to overlay a density map on a street level map but unsure how to do it. I am using the opendata available on [the police.uk website](https://data.police.uk/data/fetch/24ee2bc1-f7e5-46aa-93f3-3bb5f5b7b409/).

Each incident has a lat and long associated to it.

The code below gets me a density map.

`

```
#selecting columns we need
crimes <- dplyr::select(dataCrimesData, Crime.ID, Longitude, Latitude)
#plotting density map
ggplot(crimes, aes(Longitude, Latitude))+
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon")
```

`
Result

[image: Density Map]

I am able to draw maps with `mapview()` that just plots the crimes by the lat,long but I want to overlay the above map on a street level map.